# Uso de nonce en CSP - Google API Autocomplete

Tags: apache, google-maps, csp, nonce

Al utilizar CSP que restringen el uso de aplicar estilo en linea en una sitio web, esta regla tambien bloquea el uso de la API de Google Places Autocomplete para las direcciones, el plugin de Google agrega algunas reglas de estilo al dropdown de un campo de busqueda y el estilo no se aplica.

La documentacion de CSP sugiere utilizar el atributo nonce con un valor arbitrario de caracteres, en unos sitios encontre que debe ser una cadena de texto codificada como Base64, puede alguien aca compartir cual es la manera correcta de utilizar este atributo y si les funciona con la API de Google?

Trate de usarlo asi en archivo .htaccess, pero no me funciono

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'self' 'nonce-2C907917D4F70512155ADB6A5A58E162'  translate.google.com fonts.googleapis.com connect.facebook.net google.com translate.googleapis.com"
```

y con el nonce agregado al script

```javascript
<script nonce="2C907917D4F70512155ADB6A5A58E162" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={$G_MAP_KEY$}&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly" async></script>
```

Comment: Ponerle nonce al script de google maps API no modifica la restricción a estilos inline. (misma cosa el strict-dynamic) estás por ahora limitado a usar unsafe inline para los estilos, me parece.

Comment: El valor de `nonce` se supone arbitrario y aleatorio en cada petición, por lo cual, usar una cadena preestablecida no es correcto. Una configuración correcta debe establecer tanto la cabecera como el valor del tag de forma dinámica. Por lo general se usa un lenguaje de scripting para este propósito, como PHP.